# How change react local component state with global state if conditional...?

Tags: reactjs, components, state

my English is not good but I try, to explain my problem.

I am new in react,  I need to know how can I change local component state with global component if conditional is met..

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer because you have no code in your question. You will find you will garner a better response by providing what you have tried. However I will guess that what you need to do is `setState` according to a condition that you define.

```
setState(updater[, callback])
```

From the docs:

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.

For example in psuedo code:

```
if (predicate) {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    return {key: value};
  });
}
```

[You can start by reading the docs here for more on `setState`.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)